# Spring boot Mysql data is not saved

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to save data using spring boot + mysql. Every call gives 200 altough there is no data in the GET response.

**application.properties**

```
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smyc
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:sql/schema.sql
    spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

[image]

**UserController.kt**

```kotlin
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/users")
    class UserController(val service: UserService) {
        @GetMapping
        fun getAllUsers(): List<User> = service.getAllUsers()
    
        @PostMapping(
            "/add",
            consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE]
        )
        fun addUser(@RequestBody user: User) {
            service.addUser(user)
        }
    }
```

**UserRepository.kt**

```kotlin
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, String> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getAllUsers(): List<User>
}
```

**User.kt**

```kotlin
@Table("users")
data class User(
    val id: String,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String,
    val phone: String,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update User.kt so that it contains
`@Entity`(at class level) and `@Id`(at id level)

```
@Table("users")
@Entity
data class User(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String,
    val phone: String,
)
```

Comment: I dont have entity annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can use save method:

```
MerchandiseEntity pants = new MerchandiseEntity("Pair of Pants", 34.99);
pants = repo.save(pants);
```

Comment: I am using that